# android.playServicesVersion (Codename one)

Tags: admob, google-play-services, codenameone

Tell me please, what version of Google Play Servives a using by default? What version of Google Mobile Ads SDK (admob) is using now?

Answer (score 0):

We use `8.3.0` but some libraries such as Google Maps etc. set this to a higher value using the `minPlayServicesVersion` build hint.